как отсортировать строки в файле в рандомном порядке?
shuf filename > filerandomsort
sort -R filename > filerandomsort

эти две команды не работают
os ubuntu 22

Эти две команды работают на Ubuntu 22.

) у мну не сортирует, файл массой  10кк строк

У меня только что отсортировал файл из 10^7 строк.

@StanislavVolodarskiy сколько памяти у вас?

shuf во время работы использовал 240MB. Вы бы задали вопрос нормально. Вопрос "Не работает" не работает.

в не работает там оч мощный поток заряжаных частиц

Исправьте вопрос так чтобы на него можно было ответить. Вы не сказали ничего про свою проблему. "Не работает" и больше натурально ничего. Станьте на моё место. Как я вам помогу? Я проверил, работает. Потом проверил на большом объёме, работает. И?

@StanislavVolodarskiy не ожидаемый результат получается

Шаг в нужном направлении. А какой результат ожидается? Всё должно быть в вопросе. Если вы что-то лишнее напишете, вреда не будет. Если вы что-то важное пропустите, вопрос закроют.

@StanislavVolodarskiy вопрос в вопросе, нужно перетасовать строки в файле случайным образом

Я проверил. У меня всё тасуется. Уверен что это перемешивание пройдёт любую проверку. Что вас не устраивает? Пишите в вопросе.

К ожидаемому результату добавьте что вы получаете. В вопрос.

Подтверждаю. На Ubuntu 22 сейчас перемешал файл из 4000 строк, размер 3.8 Мб. Время 0.006с

@StanislavVolodarskiy получаю то что файл копируется из одного места в другое без перемешивания

@user666938 как вы это проверяете, учитывая, что все 10кк строк вы вряд ли можете просмотреть глазами?

@andreymal проверяю по тому что вижу на экране, первые 50-100 строк одинаковые в исходнем файле и после обработки

Вы просто перепутали файлы.

Добро пожаловать на сайт ru.SO!  рекомендую ознакомиться со справкой => https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Может нужно сохранить результаты перемешивания исходного файла source в некий промежуточный файл random, затем отсортировать оба файла и сохранить результаты в файлы sort_source, sort_random и сравнить отсортированные результирующие файлы?
